# Cygin error in android NDK

Tags: android, cygwin, android-ndk

hi all i sucessfully install Cygin and android NDK on my computer but when i run the Cygin.bat file and check wheater it install properly or not i get the following error 
        Can't open perl script "C:\Program": No such file or director

i set the PATH of Cygin in the Enviromental variable PATH.then also gettting error 
so anyone help me to solve my problem it is really thankful to them

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like a problem due to the space in "C:\Program Files". Have you tried installing Cygwin to a folder like C:\Cygwin?